# SQL SERVER How To join 2 tables

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 tables,

Table 1 StockCard

```
OutletKey   ProductKey  Date          qty
101         ABC         01/01/2014    10
101         ABC         21/02/2014    5
101         ABC         31/03/2014    5
101         ABC         05/06/2014    2
101         ABC         20/10/2014    3
101         ABC         11/11/2014    4
101         ABC         12/12/2014    7
101         ABC         05/01/2015    8
101         ABC         03/02/2015    10
```

And the second table is stock_date

```
OutletKey    StockDate
101          05/04/2014
101          14/10/2014
101          10/01/2015
```

And I want the result like this

```
OutletKey    ProductKey   StockDate   TotalQty
101          ABC          10/01/2015  44
```

So I need to calculate total qty before last date of stockdate which is 10/01/2015

Thanks

EDIT: I am writing query like this but the result is not correct.

```
Select SC.outletkey ,SC.productkey ,SD.StockDate ,Sum(SC.qty) as totalqty
From StockCard SC 
Inner Join StockDate SD 
On SC.outletkey = SD.outletkey and SC.date < SD.stockdate 
Group by SC.outletkey ,SC.productkey ,SD.StockDate
```

Comment: What type of DB is it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us your train of thought so we can help nudge you in the right direction.

Comment: Select 
SC.outletkey
,SC.productkey
,SD.StockDate
,Sum(SC.qty) as totalqty
From StockCard SC
Inner Join StockDate SD
On SC.outletkey = SD.outletkey
and SC.date < SD.stockdate
Group by
SC.outletkey
,SC.productkey
,SD.StockDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most RDBMSs, I would do it like this:

```
SELECT sc.OutletKey
    ,sc.ProductKey
    ,sd.LastStockDate AS StockDate
    ,SUM(sc.qty) AS TotalQty
FROM StockCard sc
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT OutletKey
            ,MAX(StockDate) AS LastStockDate
        FROM stock_date
        GROUP BY OutletKey
    ) sd
    ON  sd.OutletKey = sc.OutletKey
    AND sc.Date      < sd.LastStockDate
GROUP BY sc.OutletKey
    ,sc.ProductKey
    ,sd.LastStockDate
```

For SQL Server, I'd convert the `INNER JOIN` to a `CROSS APPLY`, which might perform better:

```
SELECT sc.OutletKey
    ,sc.ProductKey
    ,sd.LastStockDate AS StockDate
    ,SUM(sc.qty) AS TotalQty
FROM StockCard sc
CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT MAX(StockDate) AS LastStockDate
        FROM stock_date
        WHERE OutletKey = sc.OutletKey
    ) sd
WHERE sc.Date < sd.LastStockDate
GROUP BY sc.OutletKey
    ,sc.ProductKey
    ,sd.LastStockDate
```

I don't think it's possible to move the inequality to the correlation, so that's why it's in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
Select StockCard.OutletKey, StockCard.ProductKey, stock_date.StockDate, sum(StockCard.TotalQty) as TotalQty 
from StockCard
inner join stock_date on StockCard.OutletKey = stock_date.OutletKey
group by StockCard.OutletKey, StockCard.ProductKey, stock_date.StockDate
```

What this does...
Selects the requested columns, with a sum of the quatity.  Then joins the other table up.
Your result will be the quantities grouped by `ID`, `product`, and `date`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, work OK? I had to make some assumptions based on what little info we have on the data structure. Change the `IN` into a `NOT IN` if you want everything before that date rather than on that date.

Feedback is welcome if it doesn't quite fit what you want.

```
SELECT sd.OutletKey, sd.ProductKey, sd.StockDate, SUM(sc.qty) AS TotalQty
FROM stock_date sd
INNER JOIN StockCard sc ON sd.OutletKey = sc.OutletKey
   AND sd.ProductKey= sc.ProductKey
   AND sd.StockDate= sc.StockDate
WHERE sd.StockDate IN (
   SELECT MAX(StockDate) FROM stock_date
)
GROUP BY sd.OutletKey, sd.ProductKey, sd.StockDate
```

Not tested... so if anyone sees a problem, feel free to edit!